# What is wrong with my constructor in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, get

Is there a better way (probably..) to build a class in which i can use set/get method. 
Notice thay all the data are stock in a ArrayList.

```
public class PorterList
{
    public PorterList()
    {
         ArrayList<Porter> porList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }
    public PorterList(ArrayList<Porter> p)
    {
         ArrayList<Porter> porList = p;
    }    

    SimpleDateFormat porterDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    private Porter p = new Porter();
    private int _porterNo;
    public String getStatus(int porterNo)
    {
        _porterNo = porterNo;
        p = porList.get(_porterNo);
        return p.p_state;
    }
```

There's something wrong on that second last line p = **porList**.get(_porterNo);

I want to use something like this in my main:

```
p_L = PorterList(p)
porter_status = p_L.get(5)
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you declare ArrayList porList = p; inside the constructors , It will become local variable , so it will not be visible outside that constructor , If you want it to use at your class level declare it at globally liek below

```
public class PorterList
{
    private ArrayList<Porter> porList; 

    public PorterList()
    {

     porList = new ArrayList<>(); 

    }
    public PorterList(ArrayList<Porter> p)
    {
         porList = p;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yor ArrayList is local variable and it's your problem. It's should be a field.

```
private ArrayList<Porter> porList;
public PorterList() { 
  porList = new ArrayList<>(); 
} 
public PorterList(ArrayList<Porter> p
{ 
  porList = p; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both of your constructors you have declared local variable porList - make this a field

```
public class PorterList
{
    private ArrayList<Porter> porList; 

    public PorterList()
    {
         porList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }
    public PorterList(ArrayList<Porter> p)
    {
         porList = p;
    }
....
}
```

Comment: Do `porList = new ArrayList<>();` in the no-arg constructor and remove initializer from field, so you don't waste a `new ArrayList<>()` in the second constructor.